# when i use the autogeneratecolumns = false some columns are not bindined to datagridview If i click on between Button and ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

Actually  i have a Combo Box and button in my application .In this Appn I used autogeneratecolumns = false and i added some columns to datagridview with datapropertyname in the Button. First time When i click the button it properly Binding but When i select Combo Box After button click some columns of query related data is not binding.

**Note:Whatever i mentioned the columns with datapropertyname is not binding in datagridview when i select Combo box.**
***Vb.net***

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Queries where Querys like '%" + ddlQuerys.Text + "%'", con)
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                gvInsuredData.Columns(0).Visible = True
                gvInsuredData.Columns(1).Visible = True
                sda.Fill(ds)
 gvInsuredData.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                gvInsuredData.DataSource = dt

   gvInsuredData.Columns(2).Name = "personalPropertyItemID"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(2).HeaderText = " Item ID"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "personalPropertyItemID"

                gvInsuredData.Columns(3).Name = "personalPropertyQuantity"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Qty"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "personalPropertyQuantity"

                gvInsuredData.Columns(7).Name = "Age(y)"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Age(y)"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "personalPropertyAge"

                gvInsuredData.Columns(8).Name = "Age(m)"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(8).HeaderText = "Age(m)"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(8).DataPropertyName = "Personalpropertyagem"


                gvInsuredData.Columns(9).Name = "Unit Cost"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(9).HeaderText = "Unit Cost"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(9).DataPropertyName = "personalPropertyCost"

                gvInsuredData.Columns(10).Name = "Total Cost"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(10).HeaderText = "Total Cost"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(10).DataPropertyName = "PersonalPropertyTotalCost"


                Dim AytC As Keyoti.RapidSpell.Grid.AYTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New Keyoti.RapidSpell.Grid.AYTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
                AytC.HeaderText = "DescriptionProperty"
                AytC.Name = "Description"
                AytC.DataPropertyName = "personalPropertyDescription"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "personalPropertyDescription"
                gvInsuredData.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

                Dim AytCtb As Keyoti.RapidSpell.Grid.AYTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New Keyoti.RapidSpell.Grid.AYTDataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
                AytCtb.HeaderText = "SourceProperty"
                AytCtb.Name = "Source"
                gvInsuredData.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "personalPropertySource"
                gvInsuredData.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

**Item ID,Qty,Age(Y),Age(m),unit cost and total cost columns are not binding when i select combobox but other columns data is  binding**

Comment: Why are you configuring this grid in code instead of in the designer? If you must do it that way, set the `DataSource` last.

Comment: Actually iam using only one datagridview to bind different tables with diffrent controls, so i'm Configuring with Code only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that this is the issue but it looks awfully suspicious. You create a populate a `DataSet` named `ds`:

```vb
Dim ds As New DataSet()
'...
sda.Fill(ds)
```

but then you assign a `dt` variable that appears nowhere else in your code to the grid's `DataSource`:

```vb
gvInsuredData.DataSource = dt
```

What's up with that? Why are you creating a `DataSet` at all when all you need is a `DataTable`? I assume that `dt` is at least supposed to be type `DataTable` but where did it come from? Did you leave out some relevant code or are you actually not assigning the data source that you think you are?